# Is there a free web app similar to Animoto?

Tags: webapp-rec, video

Is there any free version of the web app which creates video from photos with background music? To be exact, I'm looking for a web app similar to [Animoto](http://animoto.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no free substitute of Animoto. All of its alternatives are commercial products with a very limited trial functionality. These alternatives are:

- [Flixtime](http://flixtime.com/)
- [Slide](http://www.slide.com/arrange)
- [Stupeflix](http://www.stupeflix.com/)
- [One True Media](http://www.onetruemedia.com/)
- [Toufee](http://www.toufee.com/)
- [ProShow](http://www.photodex.com/proshow)

Their payment plans can be found after clicking 'Learn More' links. For example, payment plan for FlixTime can be found [here](http://flixtime.com/payment/subscription/list/).

However, I've found a totally free service called [Clip Generator](http://www.clipgenerator.com/). The downsides are:

- You have to choose your music from their list (no user upload).
- Total size of images per file = 20 MB.

Answer (score 0):

[FlixTime](http://flixtime.com/)

> FlixTime turns your photos and videos into stunning and unique videos in just minutes! Sign-up for a free account, and upload your images, videos and music. Then, sit back and watch your masterpiece come together!

or

[Stupeflix Studio](http://www.stupeflix.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but they add watermark in the video. Is there any free webapp without that?

Comment: FlixTime and Stupeflix are commercial products. Please see my answer.